# Are the deferred functions passed into when() run asynchronously or syncrously?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have the following code:

```
$.when(func1(),funct2(),func3())
 .done(...)
 .fail(...);
```

I'd like to know if these functions will all be immediately called of if jQuery will call them in succession as they are resolved. According to the documentation it appears that they will run asynchronously:

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when, the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed.
>
> ...
>
> In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at that point.

The way I read this is that func1, func2, and func3 will all get fired immediately, and the master deferred object that is returned will handle calling the proper callback functions, however whenever the first reject() is detected the fail() callback will immediately fire. Is my understanding of this correct or is there something there that I am missing?

Comment: Do `func1()`, `funct2()` and `func3()` return `Deferred` objects? These functions will be called before `$.when()` is invoked, because you're calling them yourself.

Comment: Yes, this is just a hypothetical, but assume that they would all return a promise() and that they all would be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The `done` callback will only be called when *all* the `Deferred` objects are resolved.

On the other hand, the `fail` callback will be called as soon as *any* `Deferred` object is rejected, regardless of the state of the other `Deferred` passed to `$.when()`.

In other words, it works like a short-circuiting `AND` operator.